# Please add the tag [red]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[red](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red) is [already a tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/red). Please add it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please post a question using the language, drop a link to that question here and we will take care of the rest.

Update: tag created, tag definition and excerpt added. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211884/improving-the-red-implementation-of-rock-scissors-paper

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon Thank you. I have created the tag and proposed a tag definition/excerpt for it (more or less copied from Stack Overflow, with a thinner version for the excerpt).